# Lines and conics on certain K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be a ternary sextic form with integer coefficients. The surface $X_f$ defined by $w^2 = f(x,y,z)$ is then a K3 surface of genus 2.

Is it known whether it's possible to give explicit criteria on $f$ to determine:

1) the number of lines and conics that lie on $X_f$; and

2) whether these lines and conics are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: It may be useful to note that each 3-tangent (or totally tangent) line to the sextic gives a pair of lines on $X_f$. Similarly, every totally tangent conic to the sextic gives a pair of conics on $X_f$. Finally, all lines and conics on $X_f$ are obtained in this way.

Comment: @Sasha  In some sense, "conics" also include flex lines that are tangent at a non-flex point, and "hyperflex lines" (i.e., the intersection multiplicity of the line and sextic at the point is at least 4).  The inverse image in $X$ of such lines are curves of geometric genus $0$ whose intersection number with the pullback of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ equals $2$, i.e., "conics".  All of these types of lines can be read off at once from the degree $75$ equation of the dual curve parameterizing tangent lines.

Comment: @JasonStarr: The curves that you mentioned have degree 2 and geometric genus 0, but their Hilbert polynomial is wrong, so I am not sure one should consider them as conics. But in a sense that depends on the moduli problem one considers --- Hilbert scheme or moduli of maps.

Comment: @Sasha You are correct it depends on the problem we are considering.  If we are trying to find smooth genus $0$ curves, for instance to bound the cones of divisors, then the "conics" that I mentioned are irrelevant.  However, if we are trying to match reduced Gromov-Witten invariants to classic curve counts, then probably they should be included.  I completely agree that without knowing the OP's moduli problem, this is an arguable point at best.